# (For python API)To send an email with an attachment, a service is required. What is this service and how can I access this?

Tags: python, service, gmail-api

The function used to send the message is below, how can i access the service.
def SendMessage(**service**, user_id, message):

```
"""Send an email message.
  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
"""
try:
    print(service.users())  
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
    print ('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
except errors.HttpError as error:
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your code from the sample of the [Users.messages: send documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#python) or [Guide for serving emails](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages).

### Those samples are based on the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

- You have to follow all the steps explained in the quickstart including building a service with `service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)`.
- This means that you follow the [OAuth2 authentication flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and provide your code the necessary scopes for the request you want to perform - prerequisites for working with Google APIs.
- Once you obtain the `gmail service`, you are autorized for using it for requests based on the scopes you provided.
- [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#auth) tells you which scopes you need for a certain method (e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` for sending an email)
- Provided the required scope was contained in `SCOPES = [...]` when you built your `service`, you can now use this `service` for sending emails.